# Selective Export from org mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I am using org mode with code blocks to produce my slides via beamer. What I'd like to do is make this into a blog post. This needs more explanatory text. What I'd like to be able to do is export some things when exporting to e.g. html but other things when exporting to beamer. Something like this?

```
#+EXPORT :beamer
  * Stan uses "burn-in" to initialise.
  * PyMC3 uses ADVI.
#+END
#+EXPORT :html
Variational inference (VI) is a scalable technique for approximate
Bayesian inference. Automatic differentiation variational inference
(ADVI) is a way of automating VI so that all that is needed is the
model and the data.
#+END
```

Comment: It seems I might be able to use tags and drawers. I'll add a full answer later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can use draws e.g.

```
:PRESENTATION:
 * Stan uses "burn-in" to initialise.
 * PyMC3 uses ADVI.
:END:
:BLOG:
Variational inference (VI) is a scalable technique for approximate
Bayesian inference. Automatic differentiation variational inference
(ADVI) is a way of automating VI so that all that is needed is the
model and the data.
:END:
```

and then put

```
#+OPTIONS: d:(not "PRESENTATION")
```

or

```
#+OPTIONS: d:(not "BLOG")
```

There are also tags but that controls whole sections.

More info here: http://orgmode.org/manual/Drawers.html