# Include some content in org-mode only when exporting to HTML

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-ref

I'm currently exporting a document to latex and HTML and there is some content that I have to create separately for each target. For the latex target, I add the latex code as

```
#+begin_export latex
// latex code
#+end_end
```

which is not included in HTML export.

However, for the HTML export, I'd like to add the content as org-mode syntax and have org-mode parse it as usual. Therefore, using `#+begin_export html` is not an option. Obviously, the parsed content should be included only in HTML export.

I have found [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33875/selective-export-from-org-mode) that use drawers to selective export and the drawer content is parsed by org-mode according to the export target. However, it is necessary to manually specify which drawer should (not) be exported.

---

The reason I need this is because I want to include two figures side-by-side and I'm using `org-ref` for labels and references. I can directly include the latex code using the subfigure environment in a `#+begin_export latex` block and everyhting works in latex export (referencing as well as numbering).

In HTML export it's OK for the figures to be one below the other (although side-by-side would also be nice). If I directly add the HTML code in a `#+begin_export html` like the solution for the latex export, then the caption will not include the figure numbering, since `org/org-ref` doesn't touch it.

---

### Current Solution

My current solution is to use a `src` block to return the org-mode code for the figures, which it the content I only want to be included in HTML export. The reason is that with an `src` block I can add `:exports` and pass lisp code that checks the value of `org-export-current-backend`. In the case of HTML export the lisp code results in `:exports results`, while in other backends it results in `:exports none`.

```
#+begin_src python :exports (if (org-export-derived-backend-p org-export-current-backend 'html) "results" "none") :results raw
  content = """
  ,#+NAME: fig1_label
  ,#+CAPTION: Fig1 caption.
  ,#+ATTR_HTML: :width 500 :height 500
  [[file:figs/fig1.svg]]

  ,#+NAME: fig2_label
  ,#+CAPTION: Fig2 caption.
  ,#+ATTR_HTML: :width 500 :height 500
  [[file:figs/fig2.svg]]
  """
  return content
#+end_src
```

It works, but it is a bit cumbersome. It would be great if that was a flag I could pass to a `#+begin_export html` block to specify that it has org-mode markup and the content should be transformed with the regular html export. Even better if I could get actual subfigures working in HTML export (with a single org-mode code for both latex and html export).